# problemas com o erro ValueError: could not convert string to float: em python

Tags: python-3.x

como converto a string para float?
[image: programa]

[[image: eero do compilador[2]]

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Answer (score 1):

Cara você tem que certificar que só exista uma string de número para converter. Ex

```py
float('12.34')
```

Desta maneira funciona normalmente. Caso exista qualquer letra junto é preciso remover as letras e deixar somente os números para fazer a conversão. Tente depurar o que está retornando o valor que você está tentando converter, caso tenha somente números no formato string funcionará normalmente.